# Can't put a signed APK in production in play store. Problem with Andorid App Bundle

Tags: android, cordova, bundle, phonegap, html-framework-7

This is the problem
**Use the Android App Bundle format to optimize device configurations automatically or manage them on your own with several APKs.**

Create an Hybrid App with Framework7 and generate the APK signed with Phonegap Build.
I've done this before and I could load it and put in production in Play Console without any problems. But now i can't and says that I have to solve it using the *Android App Bundle* format.

The APK is signed and created with Phonegap Build, thats not the problem. I instaled in my phone, and works correct.
I have already reduced the file size a bit, but I can not reduce it any further. The final size of the APk is 4.1 mb.
I do not know how to do with Phonegap Build to create a file with an Android Bundle App format. I search everywhere, but can't find a solution.

I do not use Android Studio to make the app. It't just HTML5, JS and CSS.

Is there any way using Phonegap Build to put the app in production?

Comment: Have you run `cordova build android --release` followed by your keystore credentials?

Comment: I made the APK using Phonegap BUild service, not from the comand line. 
I'm gonna try the make a new keystore, i don't know if thats the problem.

Comment: Did you try signing it using Android Studio?

Comment: Sorry, it solved, it's was another problem, nothing related to Bundles. Thanks